# In Yii2 hasMany relationships using viaTable how should the column names be included?

Tags: yii2

In my example I have the model `User`. A `User` has many Organisations. An `Organisation` has many Users.

For the sake of clarity, I'm using some slightly unusual column names in this example.

The `user` table has the primary key column `user_a`
The `organisation` table has the primary key column `organisation_a`

We also have a join table called `user_organisation` which contains a primary key (not relevant here) plus `user_b` and `organisation_b` columns.

How do I create a relationship from the User to its Organisations in Yii2 using a `getOrganisations` a `hasMany` and a `viaTable`?

```php
public function getOrganisations()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Organisation::className(), ['column_a' => 'column_b'])
    ->viaTable('user_organisation', ['column_c' => 'column_d']);
}
```

What should I replace `column_a`, `column_b`, `column_c`, `column_d` with?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a more simple relationship in Yii2 you might start with something like the following.

Here we have a User with a single Organisation. The `user` table has the column `organisation_b` and the `organisation` table has the column `organisation_a`.

In our relationship we define these columns with the organisation column `organisation_a` followed by the user table column `organisation_b`.

```php
public function getOrganisation()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Organisation::className(), ['organisation_a' => 'organisation_b']);
}
```

Where we have a `hasMany` relationship the way we define the columns changes a little. We need to consider the link table too.

The `hasMany` part of our relationship definition now contains how the link table `user_organisation` is related to the `organisation` table. The first column should define that which exists in the `organisation` table. For us that's `organisation_a`. The second column is the relevant one in the `user_organisation` table for the Organisation. For us that's `organisation_b`.

The new `viaTable` part of our relationship now links the `individual` table to the link table `user_organisation`. The first column should define that which exists in the `user_organisation` table. For us that's `user_b`. The second column is the relevant one in the `user` table. For us that's `user_b`

```php
public function getOrganisations()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Organisation::className(), ['organisation_a' => 'organisation_b'])
        ->viaTable('user_organisation', ['user_b' => 'user_a']);
}
```

In more standard examples, you'll likely be using a lot of `id` column names in place of the less standard examples we've used here.

Comment: It was explained quite well (and IMO more clear) in documentation: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record#junction-table

Comment: The lack of a clear example in the documentation with obvious column naming and mapping—or anywhere else I could find to be honest—is exactly why I created this question.

Comment: If you think that documentation is not clear, you may consider opening  PR with improvements. But i think that example with mapping like `'user_b' => 'user_a'` is much more confusing than `'order_id' => 'id'`.